# How to use sphinx rtd theme with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I use pandoc to convert a markdown file to a html document. I wonder if it is possible to use [Sphinx rtd theme](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme) to my html document converted using pandoc:

```
pandoc mydoc.md -o mydoc.html
```

Could you tell me please how can use this template to my html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a sphinx-theme, you might simply use [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org) instead of pandoc?

But if you're only interested in the CSS the theme provides, you can tell pandoc to use that:

```
pandoc input.md -o foo.html -s --css https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css
```

See the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) for more info.